# How to increase an int attribute in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList filled with Teams, all teams have an attribute: int numberOfGoldMedals. I Also have an ArrayList filled with medals. I am trying to make a loop which increase the int attribute numberOfGoldMedals every team have depending on how many of the gold medals in the medals ArrayList has with their name on it. Below is my current loop, but I do not know how to increase the int numberOfGOldMedals.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < teamlist.size(); i++) {
        team t = teamlist.get(i);
        for (int y = 0; y < medals.size(); y++) {
            Medal m = medaljer.get(y);
            if (t.getTeamName().equals(m.getTeamName())) {
                if (m.getValue().equals("gold")) {
                    //Here I want to increase NumberOfGoldMedals++.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `Team` Class ?

Comment: Why increment? You can just reassign a new value depending on the number of medals in the other list.

Comment: As a sidenode, i´d rather store the team in a `Map<String,team>` to be able to get the team out of a collection a lot faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you should have either a `setGoldMedalCount(int value)` or `incGoldMedalCount()` method in your `team` class and call that method inside that condition.